# Bootstrap network in R and igraph

Tags: r, random, igraph, graph-theory, network-analysis

I have an iGraph network object, and I've been searching for options to do bootstrapping on that network for statistics such as degree centrality, etc...
I do know that I don't post any examples (as I don't have any specifics to present). This question is not specifically directed to one network, but to packages, or iGraph options to bootstrap any kind of network objects.

The main goal is to be able to validate by getting Confidence Intervals for A network's property such as closeness or centrality.

Comment: Have you heard of the 'bootnet' package? That should help you out

Comment: @EvanO. I did, but unfortunately their documentation is quite poor. There isn't much explaining what happens on the background. I ended up writing my own code, and incorporating it in my own package.

Comment: oh that's neat! What's your package called?

Comment: @EvanO. it's called skynet. Not specific for bootstrapping networks, but if you look at the code in the bootstrap function it might help you. https://github.com/FilipeamTeixeira/skynet